# Finding a span where the class contains a text string JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to find a span element that contains a string of text in the **class**, but could also contain other text.

```
var not_breaks = element.filter("span.this_text");
```

This works for spans where `class="this_text"` but not `class="this_text_and_more_text"` - I need to search for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you could use the [Attribute Contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
var not_breaks = element.filter("span[class*='this_text']");
```

You could also use the [Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector, but note that this is *only* guaranteed to work if the element has a single class on it:

```
var not_breaks = element.filter("span[class^='this_text']");
```

Comment: what if there is a class `class="this_text_and_dont_include"` and this class should not be included it will still be included right?

Comment: It would be yes, but that wasn't in the OPs requirements. If that's the case then I'd suggest providing a function to `filter()` to give more specific logic.

Comment: I used the first approach and it worked great! For this case it doesn't matter what the other text is, it is very different for each class, but needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

We can get all the span class with the name by using a hasclass, Will this help you

```
var pare=$('span');
$( pare ).each(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('httext')){
    alert($(this).html())
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

> I need to search for both

I'd do that with a [selector group](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping):

```
var not_breaks = element.filter("span.this_text, span.this_text_and_more_text");
//                      first ---^    comma ---^ ^---- second
```

That will retain elements matching *either* selector in the group.

Example:

```js
var element = $("span");
var not_breaks = element.filter("span.this_text, span.this_text_and_more_text");
not_breaks.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<div><span>Not a match</span></div>
<div><span class="this_text">this_text</span></div>
<div><span>Not a match</span></div>
<div><span class="this_text_and_more_text">this_text_and_more_text</span></div>
<div><span>Not a match</span></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to retrieve the any sequence as you need.

```
var regex = new RegExp("this_txt");
var elem = $("span").filter(function () {
                    return regex.test($(this).attr('class')); 
           });
console.log(elem.length);
```

regex.test function will only return true if the sequence exists.

here's the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/yt1cr2zb/